# Proper WWW-Authenticate header for OAuth provider

Tags: oauth, response-headers

In the [OAuth 1.0 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hammer-oauth-10) it is suggested to respond with the following WWW-Authenticate header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="http://server.example.com/"
```

Is it suitable to add any other informative data to this header? In case a request for a protected resource fails, would it be reasonable to include some information as to why? Such as:

```
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="http://server.example.com/", access token invalid
```

Or is this contrary to the purpose of the response header?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds a little dubious to me.  The `WWW-Authenticate` header is specified by [an RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617), which would seem to forbid the example you've given.  The OAuth spec says that you can include other `WWW-Authenticate` fields as defined by the RFC, not that you can just tack arbitrary strings onto the end of it.  I would avoid it, unless there is a defined field that you could twist to your purposes.

Comment: Your's and Tom's answers were roughly similar, I'll check your answer though since it included the link to the RFC in question.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll upvote Tom's answer for great justice, in that case, given that we answered somewhere within the same minute.

Answer (score 34):

Note for anyone just stumbling across this: The [OAuth 2.0 bearer token spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-3) adds "error", "error_description", and "error_uri" attributes to the "WWW-Authenticate" header for reporting additional error information, and it specifies when they should and shouldn't be used.

E.g.:

```
 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
 WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="example",
                   error="invalid_token",
                   error_description="The access token expired"
```

Answer (score 8):

It's against the spec to do that, and if it wasn't it would probably be something like :

```
realm="http://server.example.com", oauth_error="access token invalid"
```

I'd recommend using the response body for things like this, or maybe a `X-OAuth-Error` header.

Comment: Thank you, you're right of course. I already now use the response body for these types of messages. However, some libraries seem to expect a little more information from the header. They may be poorly implemented though.